# How do I output sorted numbers that were input in an array

Tags: c++

Here is my code. I want to be able to enter nine exam scores and then have the program sort the scores and display them in descending order. However when I enter an exam score, 65 for example, it only outputs the '6' and not the '65'. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
string tests;
double i;
double j;



std::string person;
cout << "Please enter your name" << endl;
getline( std::cin, person );


for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the grade you received for exam ";
    cout << i + 1;
    cout << " ";
    cin >> tests[i];
    cin.get();
}

for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    for (j = i +1; j < 9; j++)
    {
        double temp;
        if (tests[i] < tests[j])
        {
            temp = tests[i];
            tests[i] = tests[j];
            tests[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
{
    cout << tests[j] << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you inputing the grades into a `std::string`?  You should be using something like an `int` array or if you want to have variable number of grades then a `std::vector<int>`

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `double`s as loop control variables. `i` and `j` should have type `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're taking user input into a *string*.

A [*string*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) is a class **almost** equivalent to an array of type char, therefore calling `string tests` is **almost** the equivalent of calling `char tests[]`, Thus when you output text[*x*] you're outputting a single character, which has position *x* in the string array.

A better practice would be to use an array of type *int*:

```
int tests[9];
```

Or if you need a variable length for your array, you could use std::array, std::vector or a dynamic array.

Comment: You're welcome!
On a side note, I recommend visiting http://www.learncpp.com/, great source if you're a beginner.
Don't forget to mark the answer! :P